# Opening a PDF file in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 7 and I'm using a Phonegap template for it.
Everything looks perfect, but now I’m stuck trying to open a PDF file in the browser.
I tried the following but that doesn’t work because the url of the PDF exceeds the 2048 character limit (it’s a data url). This code runs after the deviceReady event was fired.

```
var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function () { alert(event.url); });
```

Now, I'm trying to save the PDF file to storage and then I'm trying to have it opened by the browser, but the browser doesn't show anything. I'm editing the InAppBrowser.cs code from cordovalib and I added the following lines before calling browser.Navigate(loc);

```
private void ShowInAppBrowser(string url)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    FileStream stream = store.OpenFile("test.pdf", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    var myvar = Base64Decode("the big data url");
    writer.Write(myvar);
    writer.Close();

    if (store.FileExists("test.pdf")) // Check if file exists
    {
        Uri loc = new Uri("test.pdf", UriKind.Relative);
        ...
    }
}
```

This code is returning the following error: 
Log:"Error in error callback: InAppBrowser1921408518 = TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'url': object is null or undefined"

I don’t wanna use ComponentOne.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot open pdf files from the isolated storage in the default reader for PDF files. If the file is online e.g. it has a URI for it, you can use WebBrowserTask to open it since that will download and open the file in Adobe Reader.

On Windows Phone 8 you actually can open your own file in default file reader for that extension, but I am not sure how that will help you since you target PhoneGap and Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Then does it mean that we can not open a pdf or word document in WP8 thorugh out own application? I too have the same issue, I have downloaded a pdf file in localStorage and as soon as it downloads I want to show it to user, any suggestions how do that?

Comment: @Debhere Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx for more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

Toni is correct. You could go and try to build your own viewer (which would be the same thing as using C1, but with more time involved). I worked on a port of iTextSharp and PDFSharp for WP7, but neither of which are PDF Viewers. They are good for creating PDFs and parsing them some (but to render them there is more work involved). This has been a personal quest of mine, but honestly the best I have gotten is to be able to extract some images from the PDF (and none of the text)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var assets = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var pdf = await assets.GetFileAsync("metro.pdf");
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdf);
```

This worked correctly on my Device.