# How to open file using native app in windows phone 8 using phonegap?

Tags: file, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to open a file like a pdf file in local storage using phonegap in windows phone 8 but do not find a way to do it. I have seen one similar question linked below but no code example is provided. 
[Opening a PDF file in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605021/opening-a-pdf-file-in-windows-phone)
I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this.