# how to display pdf files on mobile by using MobileFirst

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

How can we display PDF Files on BB/iOS/Android and Windows phone by using MobileFirst (MobileFirst Studio) ? These PDF actually exists in DB as binary files.

Is there any API given by IBM?

Comment: Hi Idan, We are facing issue only with Windows and BlackBerry. if you can advice ?

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst does not (and should not) provide API to display a PDF file.

I am not sure this will possible in BlackBerry, but you can google for BlackBerry API or Cordova API to display it.

As for Windows Phone it seems that if you will provide a direct URL to the PDF file the default PDF reader should be able to display it, according to: [Opening a PDF file in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605021/opening-a-pdf-file-in-windows-phone) - so that means you can use the window.open JS API to open the URL to the PDF file.

Comment: For android can we open it in Android webview directly ? right now we are downloading pdf and then user have to open outside the application. Is there any other best way ?

Comment: Android does not have a built-in PDF reader so you are limited in what you can do.